# MasterCard internet Gateway Service (MiGS) & Virtual Payment Client (VPC) Extension needed

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, payment, payment-gateway, virtual

I need a MasterCard internet Gateway Service (MiGS) & Virtual Payment Client (VPC) Extension for magento 1.9.2.4. Its needed for Bank to Magento integration you can suggest any good extension please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**MiGS Payment Gateway For Magento 1.9**

You can Download [Thinkhigh_VPCpaymentgateway](https://www.versioneye.com/php/connect20:thinkhigh_vpcpaymentgateway/1.0.1) Extension to integrate 
MasterCard internet Gateway Service (MiGS)  with
magento 1.9.2.4.

MiGS uses MD5 hash as default and now it converted to SHA256.
So you have to made some changes in Coding also

- open the file C:YOURPROJECT\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\vpcpaymentgateway\redirect.phtml
- Replace the code with below code

```
 $RedirectUrl=Mage::helper('vpcpaymentgateway')->getRedirectUrl();
if($RedirectUrl){

   $post_data=Mage::getModel('vpcpaymentgateway/paymentconnection')->getPostData();

    $secretHash=Mage::helper('vpcpaymentgateway')->getSecureHash();

    $data = array(
        "vpc_AccessCode" => $post_data['vpc_AccessCode'],
        "vpc_Amount" => $post_data['vpc_Amount'],
        "vpc_Command" => $post_data['vpc_Command'],
        "vpc_Currency" => $post_data['vpc_Currency'],
        "vpc_Gateway" => $post_data['vpc_Gateway'],
        "vpc_Locale" => $post_data['vpc_Locale'],
        "vpc_MerchTxnRef" =>  $post_data['vpc_MerchTxnRef'],
        "vpc_Merchant" => $post_data['vpc_Merchant'],
        "vpc_OrderInfo" => $post_data['vpc_OrderInfo'],
        "vpc_ReturnAuthResponseData" => $post_data['vpc_ReturnAuthResponseData'],
        "vpc_ReturnURL" => $post_data['vpc_ReturnURL'],
        "vpc_SecureHashType" => 'SHA256',
        "vpc_Version" => $post_data['vpc_Version'],

    );



    ksort($data);
    $hash = null;
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        if (in_array($k, array('vpc_SecureHash', 'vpc_SecureHashType'))) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((strlen($v) > 0) && ((substr($k, 0, 4)=="vpc_") || (substr($k, 0, 5) =="user_"))) {
            $hash .= $k . "=" . $v . "&";
        }
    }
    $hash = rtrim($hash, "&");

    $secureHash = strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', $hash, pack('H*', $secretHash)));
    $paraFinale = array_merge($data, array('vpc_SecureHash' => $secureHash));
     ksort($paraFinale);

    $actionurl = 'https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?'.http_build_query($paraFinale);


    header("Location:".$actionurl);
}
```